# What is the story of Devi Chhinamastika?

Tags: puranas, durga, parvati, dasha-mahavidya, chinnamasta

One of the [Mahavidyas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahavidya) is named [Chinnamastika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chhinnamasta)/Chinnamasta devi , I want to know about her.

What is her story of origin and why did she appear as one of the Mahavidyas?

Comment: Chinnamastika is not an avatar she is one of the dashmahavidya of devi or swaroopa of devi. A mahavidya is an aspect of devi parvati see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahavidya

Answer (score 3):

I have discussed about the picture and iconography of the goddess in my another [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17887/7853). It is well known that she is one of prime goddesses in the shakta tradition. She is one of the cosmic manifestation of parA shakti.

> The most popular account of Chinnamasta’s origin appears in the
>   **Pranatosini**-**tantra**. It states that the goddess Parvati, Siva’s wife,
>   goes bathing with her two attendants, Dakini and Varnini. The two
>   women are hungry and ask Parvati for food. She tells them to wait and
>   they can eat once they are home. However, after further begging from
>   her companions, the merciful goddess and Mother of the Universe,
>   severs her head with her fingernails and her blood nourishes her
>   attendants. Following this event, Parvati is henceforth known as
>   Chinnamasta (Kinsley 1998:147). This origin story emphasizes maternal
>   self-sacrifice in order to satiate her companions. Scholars note the
>   interesting choice of blood instead of maternal milk for nutrients.
>   The nourishment symbolizes renewal of the universe (Kinsley 1998:150).
>
> Public and private worship of Chinnamasta is not very popular due to
>   her aggressive nature and worshipping her is viewed as dangerous. It
>   is said that those who worship her are of three types: yogis, world
>   renouncers, or heroic in nature (Kinsley 1998:164). Tantric practices
>   allow a practitioner to develop siddhis (supernormal powers) and
>   achieve the ultimate goal of liberation. The **Sakta Pramoda**,
>   **Tantrasara**, and **Sri Chinnamasta Nityarcana** outline the worship rituals
>   for Chinnamasta. There are nine sections of practice prescribed by the
>   Sakta Pramoda including visualized meditation, drawing of the yantra
>   (sacred diagram), and explication of the mantra (sacred utterance). [Source](http://www.mahavidya.ca/2015/03/10/chinnamasta/)

Comment: There is a big temple in Rajrappa (Jharkhand) of Maa Chinnamastika and everyones worship with full dedication but yes, goats are slaughtered too..